# JWT tokens generated but user still not logged in ASP.Net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm currently following a tutorial [here](https://fullstackmark.com/post/13/jwt-authentication-with-aspnet-core-2-web-api-angular-5-net-core-identity-and-facebook-login) and so far I have been able to generate JWT tokens successfully. I created an authorized controller (`Dashboard`), but the response always resulted in 404 unauthorized so I commented it out which resulted in a "`Sequence containing no matching element`" error being thrown in my Get method; meaning "`id`" wasn't found but clearly, as seen in the attached image, "id" is present.
Lastly, I tried `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` but this always resulted in `false`. What am I doing wrong?

*DashboardController.cs*:

```
namespace JwtTest.API.Controllers
{
//   [Authorize(Policy = "ApiUser")]
  [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
  public class DashboardController : Controller
  {
    private readonly ClaimsPrincipal _caller;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _appDbContext;

    public DashboardController(UserManager<AppUser> userManager, ApplicationDbContext appDbContext, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
      _caller = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;
      _appDbContext = appDbContext;
    }

    // GET api/dashboard/home
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Home()
    {
      var userId = _caller.Claims.Single(c => c.Type == "id");
      var customer = await _appDbContext.Customers.Include(c => c.Identity).SingleAsync(c => c.Identity.Id == userId.Value);

      return new OkObjectResult(new
      {
        Message = "This is secure API and user data!",
        customer.Identity.FirstName,
        customer.Identity.LastName,
        customer.Identity.PictureUrl,
        customer.Identity.FacebookId,
        customer.Location,
        customer.Locale,
        customer.Gender
      });
    }
  }
}
```

*Startup.cs*:

```
namespace JwtTest.API {
    public class Startup {

        private const string SecretKey = "iNivDmHLpUA223sqsfhqGbMRdRj1PVkH";
        private readonly SymmetricSecurityKey _signingKey
            = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SecretKey));
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>
                (x => x.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddSingleton<IJwtFactory, JwtFactory>();
            services.TryAddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

            services.AddMvc();
            // services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>()
            //     .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            //     .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


            var jwtAppSettingOptions = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(JwtIssuerOptions));

            services.Configure<JwtIssuerOptions>(options => {
                options.Issuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)];
                options.Audience = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Audience)];
                options.SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(_signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

            });

            var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)],

                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Audience)],

                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = _signingKey,

                RequireExpirationTime = false,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            };

            services.AddAuthentication(options => {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(configureOptions => {
                configureOptions.ClaimsIssuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)];
                configureOptions.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
                configureOptions.SaveToken = true;
            });

            var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>(o => {
                o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                o.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            });

            builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, typeof(IdentityRole), builder.Services);
            builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();


            // api user claim policy
            services.AddAuthorization(options => {
                options.AddPolicy("ApiUser", policy =>
                    policy.RequireClaim(Constants.Strings.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Rol, Constants.Strings.JwtClaims.ApiAccess));
            });

            services.AddAutoMapper();
            services.AddMvc().AddFluentValidation(fv =>fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>());
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
            if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseExceptionHandler(
          builder =>
          {
            builder.Run(
                      async context =>
                      {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

                    var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                    if (error != null)
                    {
                      context.Response.AddApplicationError(error.Error.Message);
                      await context.Response.WriteAsync(error.Error.Message).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                  });
          });

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

*AuthController*:

```
namespace JwtTest.API.Controllers {
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class AuthController : Controller {
        private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
        private readonly IJwtFactory _jwtFactory;
        private readonly JwtIssuerOptions _jwtOptions;

        public AuthController(UserManager<AppUser> userManager, IJwtFactory jwtFactory, IOptions<JwtIssuerOptions> jwtOptions) {
            _jwtFactory = jwtFactory;
            _jwtOptions = jwtOptions.Value;
            _userManager = userManager;

        }

        [HttpPost("login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]CredentialsViewModel credentials)
        {
            if(!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);

            var identity = await GetClaimsIdentity(credentials.UserName, credentials.Password);
            if(identity == null)
                return BadRequest(Errors.AddErrorToModelState("login_failure", "Invalid username or password", ModelState));

            var jwt = await Tokens.GenerateJwt(identity, _jwtFactory, credentials.UserName, _jwtOptions, new JsonSerializerSettings {
                Formatting = Formatting.Indented
            });
            return new OkObjectResult(jwt);
        }

        private async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GetClaimsIdentity(string userName, string password) 
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
                return await Task.FromResult<ClaimsIdentity>(null);

            var userToVerify = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);

            if(userToVerify == null) return await Task.FromResult<ClaimsIdentity>(null);

            if(await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(userToVerify, password))
                return await Task.FromResult(_jwtFactory.GenerateClaimsIdentity(userName, userToVerify.Id));

            return await Task.FromResult<ClaimsIdentity>(null);
        }
    }
}
```

*AccountsController*:

```
namespace JwtTest.API.Controllers {
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class AccountsController : Controller {
        private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _appDbContext;
        public AccountsController(UserManager<AppUser> userManager, IMapper mapper, ApplicationDbContext appDbContext) {
            _appDbContext = appDbContext;
            _mapper = mapper;
            _userManager = userManager;

        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] RegistrationViewModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var userIdentity = _mapper.Map<AppUser>(model);

            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(userIdentity, model.Password);

            if(!result.Succeeded) return new BadRequestObjectResult(Errors.AddErrorsToModelState(result, ModelState));

            await _appDbContext.Customers.AddAsync(new Customer {
                IdentityId = userIdentity.Id,
                Location = model.Location
            });
            await _appDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            return new OkObjectResult("Account created");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you stepped through to see what the Id value in your controller action is, and where the exception actually occurs? Dumping code the question doesn't really help. I'd actually take a guess that `SingleAsync` is causing the exception just by looking at that code.

Comment: Yes, I have passed through the code and the error occurs before the `SingleAsync`. It occurs at  `var userId = _caller.Claims.Single(c => c.Type == "id");` because the claims aren't passed to the controller there is no Claims to operate on and this throws the error. I don't understand why this is happening because in the startup class, I already have `services.TryAddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with this code.

Make sure that **appsettings.json** is on the main folder of the project. (Same as **startup.cs**).

Since there are setting of audience and issuer that are not being imported. That results to a fail in authentication.

That should fix your issue.

Comment: Why does having the appsettings in the main folder resolve the issue?

Comment: Since there are setting of audience and issuer that are not being imported. That results to a fail in authentication.